# Redirection problem after authentification

Tags: angular, express, mlab

so when I submit the login form, instead of going to the 'myAds' page, it stays in the login page

my code look like that in the login.componenent.html

```
<form role="form" #connexion = "ngForm" [formGroup]="login" (ngSubmit)="authentifier($event)">
          <div class="alert alert-danger" *ngIf="message !== ''" [hidden]="close" >
            {{message}}
            <button type="button" class="close" aria-label="Close" (click)="buttonclose()" >
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">

            <div class="alert alert-danger " *ngIf="login.controls['email'].valid && !login.controls['email'].touched">
            Email non validé
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- Input email -->
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="sender-email" class="control-label">Email:</label>

            <div class="input-icon"><i class="icon-user fa"></i>
              <input id="sender-email" type="text" placeholder="Email" [(ngModel)]="email" name="email"
                     class="form-control email" formControlName="email">
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- Input Passe word -->
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="user-pass" class="control-label">Mot de passe:</label>
            <div class="input-icon"><i class="icon-lock fa"></i>
              <input  id="user-pass" formControlName="pass" class="form-control input-lg"
                     placeholder="Mot de passe" type="password" [(ngModel)]="pass" name="pass">
            </div>
          </div>
          <!-- Submit -->
          <div class="form-group">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary  btn-block" [disabled] = "login.invalid">Se connecter</button>
          </div>
                </form>
```

and in my login.component.ts

```
authentifier(event){
event.preventDefault();
let Nuser = {email : this.email, pass : this.pass};
this.loginService.getUser(Nuser).subscribe(res => {
    console.log(res);
    localStorage.setItem('token', res.token);
    localStorage.setItem('type', res.type);
    localStorage.setItem('id', res.id);
    location.reload();
    this.router.navigate(['/MyAds']);
  }, err =>{ console.log(err)
  this.message = 'email ou mot de passe est incorrect';
  this.close = false;
});
  }
```

in login.service.ts I call the API

```
getUser(user) {
return this._http.post('http://localhost:3333/api/signin',user).map(res=>res.json());
  }
```

and for last in the back end

```
router.post("/signin", function (req, res) {
console.log("|" + req.body.email + "|");

db.utilisateur.findOne({
        email: req.body.email //here I tried the json.parse
    },

    function (err, user) {
        if (err) throw err;
        if (!user) {
            res
                .status(401)
                .send({
                    success: false,
                    msg: "Authentication failed. User not found."
                });
        } 
        else {
            //Ajout test email validation  
            //si (user.valide == false) n existe pas return 'compte pa valide'
            comparePassword(req.body.pass, user.pass, function (err, isMatch) {
                if (isMatch && !err) {
                    let payload = {
                        subject: user._id
                    };
                    var token = jwt.sign(payload, databaseConfig.secret);
                    var id = user._id;
                    var type = user.type;
                    res.json({
                        token,
                        id,
                        type
                    });
                } else {
                    res
                        .status(401)
                        .send({
                            success: false,
                            msg: "Authentication failed. Wrong password."
                        });
                }
            });
        }
    }

);
});
```

I just wish that when I click the submit button I don't get redirected to the login page

Comment: What for do u need location.reload() before routing?

Comment: helps me reload the page from the cache

Comment: what for if u route after that?

Comment: so that the header of the page can display the name of the user who logged in